# Block bots based on js collected data

Tags: javascript, php, bots

I made a JS file that can be included in external webpages and gathers info about the `visitor` and when the visitor is clearly a bot that needs to be blocked, how can i block that bot with PHP, based on the response off that JS file? `cURL`? or better solution maybe?

Comment: Bots are likely to ignore the JavaScript code.  What's the eventual goal here?  What problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: My goal is to block Bad bots with data i collected with the included JS file in the page. So a better question will be: how can i use JS data to block bad bots with PHP? Visitors who have JS turned off are not welkom at all and will be blocked. For some specific browser info/fingerprinting JS is neccesary. So in what order i proces the data to block the bot with PHP?

Comment: I that case you might create a cookie with JS and read it with PHP, if the cookie is not right you kill the request. Seems kinda odd though

Comment: i'm wondering how most (paid) bot-management services handling this? But thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Dave: You have a few conflicting thoughts there... *"Visitors who have JS turned off [...] will be blocked"* and *"How can I use JS to block?"*  That's kind of my previous point... If the client isn't executing the JS code (bots generally won't) then by definition you can't use JS to respond to them.  This might be a good time to step back and consider what it is you're really trying to accomplish.  Why are such bots (or any user who doesn't use JS) considered so harmful here?  What's the underlying problem that needs to be addressed?

Comment: I want to block bad bots, not only with the usual header and ip blocks,  so again... 'visitors' that dont accept JS are blocked, the rest off the bad bots can be headless browsers used as scrapers etc etc.. for that kind off bad bots its neccesary to look a little deeper with JS. And.... if the unwanted 'visitor' is a bot/headless browser..i want to block that visit, clear now?? Just block unwanted trafic. But what is the technical logic after collecting data with JS to block the visit with PHP or something else.